# The Original Toy Story?

Tags: story-identification

Some show where the stuffed animals were "alive" but if people caught them moving or out of place then they lost animation (died). It could of been a movie or a Xmas special. I was so young (80's) I can't remember more.

Comment: I'd suggest reading the Tour under the help menu above to get a better idea of a good question. You were young in the 80's, but was the show new when you saw it? And did they actually die (never moving again) or just lose animation while observed? Was it a cartoon? More info increases the odds of identification.

Comment: Did it include multiple types of toys that did this or just one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be thinking of the Jim Henson TV special [The Christmas Toy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Christmas_Toy), or the spinoff [Secret Life of Toys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Life_of_Toys).

Comment: That could be it. I'd have to watch the whole thing. My only clear memory of it is of some toys peeking down the stair case in a 'omg don't get caught' moment.